# Update blog post with PHP OOP

Tags: php, sql, pdo, sql-update

I don't understand why my blog posts aren't edited. I have a class ('blog') with the method update_post() with three parameters. Here's my code (I skipped the connection and other parts since I know they're working):

```
<?php
class blog{
function update_post($id, $title, $contents) {
        try {
            $update = $this->db->prepare("UPDATE posts SET title = $title, contents = $contents WHERE id = $id");
            $update->execute();
        }
        catch (PDOException $e) {

        }
    }
}

$post = new blog;

if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
    if (isset($_POST['publish'])) { // If submit button is clicked
        $id = $_GET['id'];
        $title = $_POST['title'];
        $contents = $_POST['contents'];
        $post->update_post($id, $title, $contents);
    }
}
?>
```

EDIT: So, it seems I had multiple errors. The original code above comes from two files, my class.blog.php file and the page with HTML form ('edit_post.php'). After some experiments I found that the error must lie in the edit_post page. I replaced the second "if statement" with "if (1 < 2)" and then my posts are updated. Here's the larger part of the edit_post page.

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
    if (isset($_POST['publicera'])) {
        $id = $_GET['id'];
        $title = $_POST['title'];
        $contents = $_POST['contents'];
        $post->update_post($id, $title, $contents);
    }
?>
<form method="post" action="edit_post.php">
    Titel:<br /> 
    <input type="text" name="title" size="80" value="<?php $post->get_title($_GET['id']); ?>"><br />
    Inlägg:<br /><textarea name="contents" rows="20" cols="80"><?php $post->get_contents($_GET['id']); ?></textarea>
    <br /><input type="submit" name="publicera" value="Publicera!">
</form>

<?php
} else {
$post->show_post_list();
}
?>
```

EDIT #2: Solved! Apart from the erroneous SQL query I needed to modify the value of the form action to `action="edit_post.php?id=<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>"`.

Comment: If this code gives any error then please mention here

Comment: I'm uploading to my web host, and error messages are never displayed there. I guess I should configure my code to display errors.

Comment: `$post = new blogg;` should be `$post = new blog;` (one g), right ? Also using prepared statements like this is fully redundant.

Comment: Your query is failing because the vars `$title`, `$contents` are not quoted.  They should be [properly bound parameters](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php). Otherwise, you get _none_ of the security offered by the prepared statement, plus a potentially broken query.

Comment: Michael: Sure OK, but I use the same syntax for adding/deleting categories, adding posts etc. Perhaps I should bind them, but is that really the problem here? The code should still update posts?

Comment: @Vienno No it _won't_ update posts because unless you have passed in those variables surrounded by single quotes like `$title = "'The quoted title'";`, the query is _invalid_ and will fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query fails because it is syntactically invalid. This is due to the fact that the variables `$title, $contents, $id` are passed in as unquoted strings directly into the PDO prepared statement. You are not getting any of the security benefits of the prepared statement, and indeed your query is both highly vulnerable to SQL injection and *broken* since the variables are not quoted.

It should use properly bound parameters:

```
function update_post($id, $title, $contents) {
    try {
        // Bind named parameters
        $update = $this->db->prepare("UPDATE posts SET title = :title, contents = :contents WHERE id = :id");
        // Pass the values in an array to execute()
        $update->execute(array(':title' => $title, ':contents' => $contents, ':id' => $id));
    }
    catch (PDOException $e) {
         // Or handle the error, assuming you have PDO setup in ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
         echo "Error in query!!!";
         print_r($this->db->errorInfo());
    }
}
```

If the rest of your application is also using patterns like your original incorrect query (though correctly quoted if they work), you are advised to update them to use bound parameters as above.  Otherwise, we must assume they are also vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It didn't solve the problem but after some experiments, at least I know this function is doing its job. I must have another error, and I think it's in the class instantiation part. See edited post above.

Comment: @Vienno I see no edits above. Your instantiation as you have it now is correct. Turn on error_reporting if you are having a problem elsewhere. `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: Sorry, it's edited now. Also, I'm running on a remote server so I don't have access to the configuration files. But I'll try and google for different solutions on how to turn error reporting on.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try all that now.

Comment: The var dump of the POST array displayed the following but I'm not sure what to make of it: `array(3) { ["title"]=> string(8) "My Title" ["contents"]=> string(16) "Random test text" ["publicera"]=> string(10) "Publicera!" }`

Comment: @Vienno Then everything looks to be in order with that code. `$_POST['publicera']` is set, so it should enter that conditional.

Comment: I must have messed up elsewhere. Thanks (for the last time) for helping me verify that the parts we have discussed here ought to work now.